# pipでpyperclipがインストールできません: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83

Tags: python

pip install pyperclip をコマンドプロンプトで入力すると以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 81: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 81: invalid start byte
```

文字コード関連のエラーからなと思いコマンドプロンプトのchcpを使ってutf-8にしたりして、実行したりしましたが、結局インストールできませんでした。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/99429

Answer (score 1):

コマンドプロンプトで `chcp 65001` でもだめだったんですね。

根本的な問題は https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4110 で報告されていて、次のpip-10.0では修正されるそうです。しかし、今使えないのは困ると思うので、リリースまでの間、開発版を使うとよさそうです。

```
python -m pip install -U https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/master.zip
```

これで、pip-10.0.0.dev0がインストールされます。

手元のWindows環境(Win10 1709 (16299.19) + Python-3.6.2(32bit) + pip-9.0.1) では同様の問題が起きたことがないので、これで解決するかは確認できていませんが、試してみる価値はありそうです。

Comment: 丁寧な回答誠にありがとうございます。色々なサイトを見ていった結果、まずpipとはパッケージ管理ソフトであるということはわかりました。

Comment: しかし自分がなにか根本的なことがわかっていないようなきがします。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトで上記のコードを実行しましたが、No module named pip　とかえってきました。カレントディレクトリが間違っているのでしょうか？　一応C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts>　になっています。

Comment: try this as well `python3 -m pip install -U ...`

Answer (score 0):

**自己解決しましたので考察を書いておきます**
まずはじめに僕の質問に回答してくださったかたへ本当に感謝しております。
一睡してから、考えていたらなんとなく問題が見えてきました。自己解決できたので原因だと思われる部分について書きます。

visual studioのpython と　anaconda の２つのpythonをインストールしていた
疑わしかったので、まず両方ともアンインストール
anacondaを再インストール
コマンドプロンプトで 
python -V, pip-V, pip list
を実行してバージョンと、pipリストを確認
pip 9.0.1, Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.で問題ありません。リストの方も問題ないようです。
そしてpip install pyperclipを実行すると無事にインストールできました。

まとめ

エラー内容はUnicodeDecodeErrorでpip installできない。でしたが、
僕みたいにvisual studioのpython と anaconda を両方ともインストールしていたらおかしなことになるかもしれません。

あとは頭の中でループして思考停止していたら一旦寝てからまた考えるとなにか閃きがあるかもしれません。

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts内にあるpip.exeを実行する必要があるかもしれません。(これをすることでなにがおきているのか説明できませんが同ディレクトリ内にある。pip listが全てインストールされるのではないと思われる)